# Arduino plotting error "command not recognized" m18 (GRBL + G-CODE)

Tags: arduino-uno, g-code

I'm new to Arduino and I am creating a project called (DIY CNC PLOTTER) for my final design project in school, the following are the list of part that I'm currently using.

Hardware:
1 Arduino Uno v3
1 L923D Shield
2 DVD Stepper Motor
1 Micro Servo S90 Motor
1 12V and 5V supply   (This is made of PC power supply, but I'm only using 5V)

Software:

1. XLOADER
2. GRBL 1.1 Hex File connected to UGS (This never worked for me)
3. GRBL 0.8 Hex File connected to UGS (This never worked for me)
4. UGS            (No response at all from lower to higher version)
5. Processing 3.3 (this works fine for me but it has on very limited functions)
6. GCTRL          (The up and down and left to the right arrow
                  has no response)
7. Inkscape       (Works fine)

ERROR:

M18 (Drive off)

command not recognized: m18

As of now, that is the error which I'm currently having during the plotting process. I've scoured the internet day and night hoping to find an answer to this issue but the more I read the more I get confused. But I've read in some post that the problem is that the GBRL CODE is not supporting the M18 and M17 G-Code, so is there any way that I can tweak the GRBL code to remove add the M18 and M17 to make it work?

I watched so many tutorials and followed the same process on how to flash Arduino using but still no luck, I hope you guys can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, did you get anything working ? I have similar issues.

Comment: Yes, I used GCTRL instead of UGS.

Comment: How much time does it take to upload `gcodes` file? Does it start to move immediately ?
In my case UGS works better but it uploads file for really long time. It uploads for 5-8 minutes then starts to move than 5-8 min again than move a bit and it repeats few times.... so it does not draw picture in one run but by pieces...

Comment: What types of motor driver you used in your project?

Regarding uploading G-Code files, I don't see any abnormalities like what you are facing right now. It will only take a second for the stepper motor to kick in after I click the G-code for plotting.

Comment: I've already figured out. It was because `gcode` file contained some commands for checks and to wait for results:
```
M300 S30 (pen down)
G4 P150 (wait 150ms)
M300 S50 (pen up)
G4 P150 (wait 150ms)
M18 (disengage drives)
M01 (Was registration test successful?)
M17 (engage drives if YES, and continue)
```
Here `M17 (engage drives if YES, and continue)` stuck whole the process....